# Getting RESULT_FIRST_USER after load full wallet (Android Pay)

Tags: android, android-pay

I want to integrate Android Pay in my App (yes, I know that Android Pay is depreceted). It works fine, but when I'm trying to load full wallet:
`Wallet.Payments.loadFullWallet(googleApiClient, fullWalletRequest, FULL_WALLET_REQUEST);`

but I always getting `RESULT_FIRST_USE` code. What does it mean?

Comment: I don't understand, why use the deprecated API instead of the Google Pay API which replaced it?